# overriding cell style for angular kendo grid

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I am trying to change the padding of the cell and set it to smaller values based on the resolution. But i have not been successful in doing do. The only option that had worked for me is by setting the style on the column:

[style]="{'padding':'5px'}"

I have tried rowClass, class etc. But none seem to have any effect on the template. even tried specifying the padding using .k-grid th, .k-grid td. But it had no effect. If any one was successful, please let me know how we could change the style on the class based on resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by specifying the following on my component

encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None

also its important to add ".k-grid" in the style. So it should be something like

.k-grid .no-padding{
    padding :0px
}